# Blitzstein Problem 55: Counting Probability Confusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is the problem I am doing:

> Take a deep breath before attempting this problem. In the book
> Innumeracy [22], John Allen Paulos writes:
>
> Now for better news of a kind of immortal persistence. First, take a
> deep breath. Assume Shakespeare’s account is accurate and Julius
> Caesar gasped [“Et tu, Brute!”] before breathing his last. What are
> the chances you just inhaled a molecule which Caesar exhaled in his
> dying breath?
>
> Assume that one breath of air contains 10^22 molecules, and that there
> are 10^44 molecules in the atmosphere. (These are slightly simpler
> numbers than the estimates that Paulos gives; for the purposes of this
> problem, assume that these are exact. Of course, in reality there are
> many complications such as different types of molecules in the
> atmosphere, chemical reactions, variation in lung capacities, etc.)
>
> Suppose that the molecules in the atmosphere now are the same as those
> in the atmosphere when Caesar was alive, and that in the 2000 years or
> so since Caesar, these molecules have been scattered completely
> randomly through the atmosphere. You can also assume that
> sampling-by-breathing is with replacement (sampling without
> replacement makes more sense but with replacement is easier to work
> with, and is a very good approximation since the number of molecules
> in the atmosphere is so much larger than the number of molecules in
> one breath).
>
> Find the probability that at least one molecule in the breath you just
> took was shared with Caesar’s last breath, and give a simple
> approximation in terms of e

It seemed to be something like the DeMontmort problem from the textbook.

I found a solution and I went to check it against this site

https://solverer.com/library/joseph_blitzstein/introduction_to_probability/exercise_1-57

And I saw something that is different:

I understand:
$P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}) = (\frac{1}{10^{22}})^{n}$.

But the series he presents I don't understand how he simplifies

$$
-1*\sum_{i=1}^{10^{22}} \left( \frac{-1}{10^{22}} \right)^{i}
$$

into

$$
 = \left(1 - \frac{1}{10^{22}}\right)^{10^{22}}
$$

---

In fact I don't understand why there is no choose in the series. I understand there is

$\frac{10^{22}}{10^{44}}$ chance of one molecule being Caesar's but there are $10^{22}$ that the molecule could be.

I would think we need
$$
-1*\sum_{i=1}^{10^{22}} \binom{10^{22}}{i} \left(  \frac{-1}{10^{22}} \right)^{i}
$$

Through some hand waving I can see how this simplifies to something around

$$ 1 - e^{-1}$$

Can someone show me the steps he used to simplify the series and explain why he is right?

Comment: Yes - both the intermediate steps and final answer are wrong.  Note that PIE is a confusing approach here - the complement is the intersection of a bunch of independent events.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying thanks.

That series in the middle of his answer threw me off, is that even related to the method you're mentioning? @Eric

Comment: Hint: It seems reasonable to assume that the number of molecules from Ceaser's last breath that you draw into your lungs in one breath follows a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Thank you @awkward that answer also seems to be in line with the other methods (PIE, Complement, Naive Definition). I think that the source I posted (https://solverer.com/library/joseph_blitzstein/introduction_to_probability/exercise_1-57) is certainly incorrect.